# How do I "globalize" binaries in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, path

For example, any binary placed in `/usr/local/bin` will run in any location. If I were to place binaries inside `/myname/local/bin` how would I be able to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 8):

All directories listed in `$PATH` are searched for executables.

Answer (score 4):

To enable your custom path by default you can add:

```
export PATH="/myname/local/bin:$PATH"
```

at the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` (for user only) or `/etc/profile` (for all system users) or any new file like `/etc/profile.d/mypath.sh`

Comment: It's a good idea to put your custom path *after* the default one unless you *want* to override default behavior. export PATH="$PATH:/myname/local/bin"

Answer (score 1):

The search path for binaries is stored in an [environment variable](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/UNIX/unix_at_fermilab/htmldoc/rev1997/uatf-62.html), PATH

You can inspect the current value:

> [steven@scstop:~]% echo $PATH
>
> /opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Note how it's a colon separated list of directories.  When you type "mybinary" at the prompt, your shell will go through these directories (in order) and execute the first one it finds.

To add /myname/local/bin to the PATH, do this (in a bash-like shell)

> export PATH=$PATH:/myname/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

Modify your $PATH environment variable in your profile to include `/myname/local/bin`.
eg `export PATH="/myname/local/bin:$PATH"`